# Implementing a view callback in Django 1.10

Tags: django

I have a URL - it will be sending me back JSON at intervals it chooses.
I want to pick up these objects on my server.
How do I write the callback function as a view?

Here's what I have so far

views.py:

```
 class CallbackView(View):
    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        data = json.loads(request.body)
        logging.info("The Callback sends me this: %s" % data)
```

urls.py (root):

```
 urlpatterns = [...
 ....,
 url(r'^api/v1/callback/?secret=XXXXXXX/$', projects.CallbackView.as_view(), name='callback')
 ]
```

Comment: Is your question 'How do I write a Django view to receive JSON sent by ajax?'

Comment: added more specifics. No ajax. The server just expects a certain URL which it knows about to be hit from an external API

Comment: So from somewhere, some JSON will arrive at that url via POST? That looks ok. What is the problem?

Comment: If this looks good, I guess I would like to test it on localhost which makes it another question.

Comment: At the core, your question is essentially how can I make a rest endpoint or a rest api, which is too broad